# obout PageIndex

Tags: .net, grid, indexing, obout

I'm using an obout grid and I wanted to know, what is the obout equivalent to PageIndex?

For example, using Visual Studio's GridView, I would say:

`if (Session["PageIndex"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["PageIndex"].ToString())) Grid1.PageIndex= (int)Session["PageIndex"];`

However;  obout doesn't have a property called "PageIndex".  What would be the equivalent?

Comment: You should refer obout's FAQ then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_paging.aspx

http://www.obout.com/grid/doc_server_side_grid.aspx#grid_tips_paging

Property is called "CurrentPageIndex"

Change pages with :

http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_paging_client.aspx

Comment: When a user clicks on one of the page numbers and the grid goes to that page, where do i store the pageindex?  I noticed that there's no event for pageindexchanged.

Comment: Client side method - getCurrentPageIndex